# data.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my json

```
[
"59191", "TypeAV - Canada", "Available", 
"422129", "TypeAA - Italy", "Available", 
"959191", "TypeBB - USA", "N/A", 
"6D968C", "TypeAV - Canada", "Available"
]
```

and js

```
$.ajax({url: 'test.json'}).done(function(data) {
  $.each(myArr, function () {
    data.forEach(function (line) {
       //do something
    });
  })
})
```

I get a `Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function`. How to fix this?

Comment: What's `myArr`? Where does it come from? And it looks like you're using the name `line` to mean two different things.

Comment: it looks like data isn't an array

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof data)` show?

Comment: Try using `$.getJSON` instead of `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`data` is apparently not an array. `$.ajax` will automatically parse the response as JSON if the server sends the `Content-type: application/json`, but it must not be doing this. Since jQuery doesn't know that the response should be parsed as JSON, it simply passes the string response to the callback function.

So you need to tell JQuery that it's JSON and needs to be parsed. The easiest way is to use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.ajax`, since you're not passing any of the complex options to `$.ajax`.

```
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
    ...
});
```

You can also use the `dataType:` option to `$.ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.json",
    dataType: "json"
}, function(data) {
    ...
});
```